# Tkinter: Center label in frame of fixed size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a frame of fixed size and place a text label in the center. I am not sure why this isn't working. I want the frame in the top left of the master frame, so NW is specified and that works fine. But changing the sticky direction of the label doesn't do anything. Help is appreciated.

```
self.f = Frame(self.master,bg="yellow",width=50,height=50)
self.f.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="NW")
self.f.grid_propagate(0)
self.f.update()
self.l = Label(self.f,text="123",anchor="center",bg="yellow")
self.l.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="wens")
```

Comment: Arrange widgets in Tkinter is a tricky task. A quickfix would be to add `pady` and `padx` to the labels grid: `self.l.grid(column=0,row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="wens")`

Comment: `W+E+N+S  != "wens"` and tricks of @VRage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.place()` for your label since your frame and your label have different parents. In `place()` you can use `anchor="center"` specify the startingpoint of your "anchor" with: `x` and `y`. Here is a working example:

```
app = Tk()
f = Frame(app,bg="yellow",width=50,height=50)
f.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="NW")
f.grid_propagate(0)
f.update()
l = Label(f,text="123",bg="yellow")
l.place(x=25, y=25, anchor="center")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. I thought that it was supposed to be bad to use pack and grid in the same window. Or is that just referring to those who have the same parent?

Comment: It is just referring to widgets with the same parent. So you can have 2 different Frames in one of them you can use `grid()` in the other you can use `pack()`

Comment: If you dont want to enter the middle values of your Frame by yourself you can also use: `l.place(x=f.winfo_width()/2, y=f.winfo_height()/2, anchor="center")` which just use the width and hight of your frame

Comment: @VRage: you don't need all that math with `place` -- you can use relative coordinates (ie: `l.place(relx=.5, rely=.5)`)

Comment: Your answer text suggests using `pack`, but your code example uses `place`. That's a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks Bryan didn't knew that.